# Adding github webhook for AWS codebuild results in error due to length

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

Creating an AWS codebuild webhook for github generates a `secret` that is quite long (2048 characters).

In the github repository I navigated to Settings --> Hooks --> Add webhook.

After adding the `payloadUrl` and secret provided by AWS, clicking the `Add webhook` button results in the following error

> There was an error setting up your hook: Config attribute records value is too long (maximum is 1024 characters)

**How can a webhook be added where the URL + secret length is greater than 1024?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Could you just use a URL shortener like https://tinyurl.com/ ?

Comment: Ramón - Did you get this error when you pasted the generated payloadUrl in a GitHub Enterprise repo? We couldn't reproduce this issue. If you could provide more details on the source repo, GHE version, that would be helpful. Also, if you could post on the AWS forums @ https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230, our engineering team can follow up for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this -

git config --system core.longpaths true

Basically you want to change core.longpaths to true